# Proper way to retain value in a ViewController for when it re-appears

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, access-control

I have two ViewControllers: `MainVC` and `SettingsVC`. 
`MainVC`s behavior depends on a value that is set at runtime in `SettingsVC`. When segueing from `SettingsVC` to `MainVC`, I hand over the value via `prepareForSegue()`. No Problem!

But when loading the `SettingsVC` again to set the value again what is the best way to have it **remember the last value** it had?

Is there **maybe a way to create a global variable**, that can be accessed by both `MainVC` and `SettingsVC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `let` outside of a class to make that variable global. Say if you have this code in your `MainVC`

```
import UIKit

var param = 1
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

Then this variable param is visible in your settingVC.

However, a better practice will be passing the variable through segue. When you segue to your `SettingVC`, simply pass the setting value back from your `MainVC` by `prepareForSegue()`. If you want to pass value when segue back, you are looking for an unwind segue. [Here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/) is a tutorial for that.

Comment: May I ask why this is not considered good practice? It seems to be the simplest solution of all.

Comment: @Marmelador Sure. So global variable may always be considered as bad practice unless you are really sure what you are doing. Say in future when you expend your project with 20 view controllers. So you may have 50 functions reading and writing to that global variable and it increase the effort to debug your project

Comment: @Marmelador No if your variable are just storing some strings. It may if you are storing an array of images

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserDefaults` for this purpose.

> An interface to the user's defaults database, where you store
>   key-value pairs persistently across invocations of your app on a given
>   device.

When you segue, set the value:

```
// someVariable is the value you want to set
// someKey is the key to identify the value for the userDefault
UserDefaults.standard.set(someVariable, forKey: "someKey")
```

And whenever you want to get the value (from wherever in your application) use the following:

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "someKey")
```